# Структура/логика сайта, PHP реализация

Tags: php

Уважаемые старшие программисты, есть такой вопрос: как реализовать вывод разного состояния сайта в зависимости от определённых условий(проверка на авторизацию) и с учётом MVC(если таковой вообще нужен), может ещё какие-то условия, о которых я пока не знаю? Прошу вас объяснить чисто логику того, как это(1 - картинка для неавторизированного пользователя, а 2 - для авторизированного) реализовать и если не сложно описать более подробно, но не сам код, а алгоритмическим языком.
[Первая картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgH9c.png) [Вторая картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMh2M.png)

Comment: Вопрос вида "какой ложкой есть суп". Реализуется с помощью условия в коде. Где именно и какое условие - зависит от кода

Comment: Да, именно это мне и нужно, "где именно и какое условие - зависит от кода", можете привести примеры со своей точки зрения реализации/своего опыта, ваш способ написания подобных условий.

Comment: if ($user) { echo "показываем одно" } else { "показываем другое" }

Comment: И на этом спасибо

Comment: И на этом пожалуйста

Comment: @Dekster931 Объясните, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее Ваш вопрос. Какие проверки Вы уже заложили? Как заводите сессию, где храните данные?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Я пока что ничего не делал, не люблю делать абы как, писать то, не зная что. Поэтому в этом вопросе я и прошу просветить меня как в общем обстоят дела и как реализовать структуру по вашему мнению, я хочу иметь представление и уже на его основе начать писать код.